# How to understand network length from geolite2 block

Tags: geoip, maxmind

I'm trying to decode the end address from the Maxmind Geolite2 database fro the ip_v4 portion, however I am used to working with class, eg /8 /16, etc. and this length of 113, 114, 112 isn't making any sense to me presumably because these are v4 addresses in v6 notation.
eg.

::ffff:1.0.128.0,113

Can anyone point me to how to translate the lengths here so that I can generate the correct mask? I want to understand it mathematically, but for some reason the penny isn't dropping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the IPv4 prefix/mask length, subtract 96 from the IPv6 prefix length. For instance, :ffff::1.0.128.0/113, from your example, is equivalent to 1.0.128.0/17 or the range 1.0.128.0 to 1.0.255.255.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was getting my address lengths mixed up which was why my maths was wrong!